# Вывод анимации или изображения на рабочий стол (как фоновое изображение)

Tags: c++, linux, c

Интересует вывод изображение не в окно, а на рабочий стол, например, чтобы видно было как человечки бегают по экрану.

Это можно как-то реализовать?

В windows вроде можно так, я такое видел.

Comment: Теоретически можно сделать окно в самом низу списка окон. Без рамки. С прозрачным фоном. Также можно будет его зафиксировать в определенном месте экрана. Скрыть из пуска. С рисованием непрозрачных элементов я не знаю что делать.